# /proc/cpuinfo showing zero cpu clock speed

Tags: linux, debian, cpu, proc

I saw an interesting issue where the `cpuinfo` file from `/proc` filesystem shows the cpu clock speed as zero. It is a physical host with no virtualization. Can someone explain to me some probable reasons behind this?

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep -i "cpu Mhz"
cpu MHz     : 0.000
cpu MHz     : 0.000
cpu MHz     : 0.000
cpu MHz     : 0.000
```

---

```
# dmidecode  | grep -A 20 CPU
        Socket Designation: CPU1
        Type: Central Processor
        Family: Xeon
        Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
        ID: D7 06 02 00 FF FB EB BF
        Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 45, Stepping 7
        Flags:
                FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
                VME (Virtual mode extension)
                DE (Debugging extension)
                PSE (Page size extension)
                TSC (Time stamp counter)
                MSR (Model specific registers)
                PAE (Physical address extension)
                MCE (Machine check exception)
                CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
                APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
                SEP (Fast system call)
                MTRR (Memory type range registers)
                PGE (Page global enable)
                MCA (Machine check architecture)
--
        Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 @ 2.60GHz
        Voltage: 0.8 V
        External Clock: 100 MHz
        Max Speed: 4000 MHz
        Current Speed: 2600 MHz
        Status: Populated, Enabled
        Upgrade: <OUT OF SPEC>
        L1 Cache Handle: 0x0007
        L2 Cache Handle: 0x0008
        L3 Cache Handle: 0x0009
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Core Count: 8
        Core Enabled: 8
        Thread Count: 16
        Characteristics:
                64-bit capable

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
        Socket Designation: CPU2
        Type: Central Processor
        Family: Xeon
        Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
        ID: D7 06 02 00 FF FB EB BF
        Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 45, Stepping 7
        Flags:
                FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
                VME (Virtual mode extension)
                DE (Debugging extension)
                PSE (Page size extension)
                TSC (Time stamp counter)
                MSR (Model specific registers)
                PAE (Physical address extension)
                MCE (Machine check exception)
                CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
                APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
                SEP (Fast system call)
                MTRR (Memory type range registers)
                PGE (Page global enable)
                MCA (Machine check architecture)
--
        Version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 @ 2.60GHz
        Voltage: 0.8 V
        External Clock: 100 MHz
        Max Speed: 4000 MHz
        Current Speed: 2600 MHz
        Status: Populated, Enabled
        Upgrade: <OUT OF SPEC>
        L1 Cache Handle: 0x000B
        L2 Cache Handle: 0x000C
        L3 Cache Handle: 0x000D
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Core Count: 8
        Core Enabled: 8
        Thread Count: 16
        Characteristics:
                64-bit capable

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
--
        Designation: SLOT1_PCIE_G3_X16(CPU1)
        Type: x16 <OUT OF SPEC>
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Long
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                Opening is shared
                PME signal is supported
                Hot-plug devices are supported

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: SLOT2_PCIE_G3_X16(CPU1)
        Type: x16 <OUT OF SPEC>
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Long
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                Opening is shared
                PME signal is supported
                Hot-plug devices are supported

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: SLOT3_PCIE_G3_X8(CPU2)
        Type: x8 <OUT OF SPEC>
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Long
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                Opening is shared
                PME signal is supported
                Hot-plug devices are supported

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: SLOT4_PCIE_G3_X16(CPU2)
        Type: x16 <OUT OF SPEC>
        Current Usage: Available
        Length: Long
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                Opening is shared
                PME signal is supported
                Hot-plug devices are supported

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
        Type: Video
        Status: Enabled
        Description: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST GPU 0.96.00 (VGA1)

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
        Type: Ethernet
        Status: Enabled
        Description: LOM 1G I350-BT2 (LAN1)
--
        Bank Locator: CPU1
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
        Manufacturer: CE00B304CE00
        Serial Number: 36119A9B
        Asset Tag: 02171321
        Part Number: M393B2G70BH0-YH9

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_A5
        Bank Locator: CPU1
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: 0x002F
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_A2
        Bank Locator: CPU1
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
        Manufacturer: CE00B304CE00
        Serial Number: 36119ADA
        Asset Tag: 02171321
        Part Number: M393B2G70BH0-YH9

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_A6
        Bank Locator: CPU1
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: 0x0030
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_A3
        Bank Locator: CPU1
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
        Manufacturer: CE00B304CE00
        Serial Number: 3611991C
        Asset Tag: 02171321
        Part Number: M393B2G70BH0-YH9

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_A7
        Bank Locator: CPU1
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: 0x0031
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_A4
        Bank Locator: CPU1
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
        Manufacturer: CE00B304CE00
        Serial Number: 361196BF
        Asset Tag: 02171321
        Part Number: M393B2G70BH0-YH9

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_A8
        Bank Locator: CPU1
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: 0x0032
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B1
        Bank Locator: CPU2
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
        Manufacturer: CE00B304CE00
        Serial Number: 36119A9C
        Asset Tag: 02171321
        Part Number: M393B2G70BH0-YH9

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B5
        Bank Locator: CPU2
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: 0x0033
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B2
        Bank Locator: CPU2
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
        Manufacturer: CE00B304CE00
        Serial Number: 36119696
        Asset Tag: 02171321
        Part Number: M393B2G70BH0-YH9

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B6
        Bank Locator: CPU2
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: 0x0034
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B3
        Bank Locator: CPU2
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
        Manufacturer: CE00B304CE00
        Serial Number: 361196C0
        Asset Tag: 02171321
        Part Number: M393B2G70BH0-YH9

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B7
        Bank Locator: CPU2
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: 0x0035
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 16384 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B4
        Bank Locator: CPU2
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
        Manufacturer: CE00B304CE00
        Serial Number: 36119AD8
        Asset Tag: 02171321
        Part Number: M393B2G70BH0-YH9

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x001D
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B8
        Bank Locator: CPU2
        Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: NO DIMM
        Serial Number: NO DIMM
        Asset Tag: NO DIMM
        Part Number: NO DIMM

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
        Type: OK
        Granularity: Unknown
        Operation: Unknown
        Vendor Syndrome: Unknown
        Memory Array Address: Unknown
        Device Address: Unknown
        Resolution: Unknown

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 18, 23 bytes
32-bit Memory Error Information
```

---

```
# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                16
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    8
CPU socket(s):         2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 45
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               0.000
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              20480K
```

Comment: What Linux distribution?  What does `dmidecode |grep -A 20 CPU` tell you  ?

Comment: @val0x00ff: Here is the output of the command which you asked: http://pastebin.com/jFqYZBgz

Comment: @val0x00ff: I am running Debian Linux 6.0

Comment: Well that's odd. As you can see, dmidecode shows the right CPU speed. `cpuinfo` seems to do something weird. Have you tried `lscpu` and what does it return?  If cpuinfo still returns inaccurate values, try to get the cpuinfo source code and compile it yourself. See what happens!

Comment: @val0x00ff: Here is the output of `lscpu`: http://pastebin.com/7UnCpnHc ,same here as well.

Comment: `dmidecode` seems to return the correct values. I'm not sure if this is `cpuinfo` not being able to get cpu speed or another bug in some library. You can ask in #debian @ irc.freenode.org to get instant help.

Comment: What kernel version? I wonder if it's due to your distribution being fairly old but your Xeon E5 being newer (Debian 6.0 dates from 2011, your CPU from 2012).

Answer (score 2):

Do you see anything when you look under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/`?

```
$ sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
2667000
```

Also you could try this. Install "cpufrequtils" package, you can change your governor and frequency using:

```
$ cpufreq-set
```

Current governor and frequency could be found using the command:

```
$ cpufreq-info
```

#### References

- [[SOLVED] /proc/cpuinfo misreporting processor speed](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=71871)